# Container of references / non-nullable pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, type-systems

I usually use references instead of pointers when I want `NULL` not to be possible. Since we can't have containers of references, what should be the type of a container that contains only non-null pointers?

Comment: Just accept that NULL is possible and use `unique_ptr` if you have it, or `shared_ptr` if you don't. Control whether or not NULL pointers show up in the container by not inserting them in the first place.

Comment: Use a container of `std::reference_wrapper`s.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That is the answer.

Comment: Write a `not_null_ptr` that will guarantee never to be null, and then make it public for the rest of us to use it

Answer (score 10):

If you were to use a container of pointers, you'd just use a container of pointers, don't place any NULL pointers in it, and move on.

However, you *can* still have a container of references if you use [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper). For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    int x = 5;

    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> v;
    v.push_back(std::reference_wrapper<int>(x));

    x = 6;

    std::cout << v[0];  // 6
}
```

### [Live demo](https://ideone.com/yBmBok)

Comment: `std::reference_wrapper` should be in the first line, and pointers should be in the second line.

Comment: Is there a reason that a container of pointers should be a more go-to design choice than reference wrapper?

Comment: @djechlin: Mostly I consider the use of references simply to get a 'not null' guarantee to be a bit silly, especially if you have to jump through hoops to make it happen.

Comment: @djechlin: I agree. The "not null" guarantee is only as good as the code surrounding it. References have other benefits and I don't really care about them too much for the "not null" reason. In code that uses your object you should already know that it's "not null".

Comment: This particular use of `reference_wrapper` has become a new favorite of mine. Non-null pointers in containers in a simple fashion.

Comment: @GManNickG: Yeah, it confuses object lifetime, though. You will almost always want to use dynamic allocation, and storing _references_ rather than pointers to dynamically-allocated objects is non-conventional and confusing.

Comment: Not sure it's so rare. I use `reference_wrapper` in various places to show observation/non-ownership, instead of pointers. This saves having to write `& `*` `->` everywhere & makes code more generic. If I want a `vector` of 'references' to objects, filtered by some criterion, I can simply declare a `vector< reference_wrapper<T> >` & then do a `copy_if` into it. Then  I can `shuffle()` the container of refs and `for` over it, achieving random iteration without having to sort the originals or use pointer syntax or etc. Of course, they break ability to use `auto`, so it's probably all a trade-off